# How to get the country place using the countryCodeIso2 from google geocoding api?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I am using

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json

My use case is this:
I have country codes in iso 2 (2 chars) format and want to get the country place from the geocoding api.

I have `JP` for example. How to call this api and get only a single response back of type `country`.

I am trying right now:

```
 $locale = 'en';
 $response = $this->httpClient->get(
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
            [
                RequestOptions::HTTP_ERRORS => false,
                RequestOptions::QUERY => [
                    'key' => 'apikey',
                    'address' => urlencode('JP'),
                    'components' => 'country',
                    'language' => (string)$locale,
                ]
            ]
        );
```

and get no results as expected as the country code is not an address..

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

I get 0 results like this. I am not seeing in the documentation any countrycode or similar field but just the address.

I am open to use also the google maps service not only limited to the geocoding so any suggestion is welcome. THanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be sending a malformed request to the Geocoding API, such as

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country&address=JP

which indeed returns `ZERO_RESULTS`. The correct request would be

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:JP

Perhaps this will work:

```
                RequestOptions::QUERY => [
                    'key' => 'apikey',
                    'components' => 'country:JP',
                    'language' => (string)$locale,
                ]
```

Note that the `address` parameter is not necessary if the `components` parameter is correctly formatted.

If you are wondering why `ZERO_RESULTS` are returned for `address=JP`, the short answer is that, in a global context, `JP` all by itself is too ambiguous.

To get a more concrete idea, I would suggest you try going to maps.googlemaps.com and type just `JP` on the search box and then, *and this is the important bit*, just hit the **Enter** key (and **not** click/tap on any suggestions). In my case, the result is a list of businesses such as "J.p. Motorcycles" or "J & P Fine Art", depending on what part of the world is visible on Google Maps at the moment of hitting the Enter key.